# how to properly write nested routes?

Tags: reactjs

I wrote the following, but only /English and /Blog can load the component correctly.
/English/GRE starts to fail. Do you know why?

```
function App() {
  return (
    <>
    <Router>
      <Navbar/> 
      {/* Why does the following code doesn't work.
      Error: "No routes matched location "/English/GRE""
      */}
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' exact element={<Home />}/>
          <Route path='English' element={<English />}/>
            <Route path='GRE' element={<GRE />}/>
              <Route path='Confusingwords' element={<Confusingwords />}/>
              <Route path='Mnemonics' element={<Mnemonics />}/>
          <Route path='Blog' element={<Blog />}/>
      </Routes>

    </Router>
  </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Not an answer since that's from memory alone, but you need to render the "Outlet" component from React-router into your parent route's component so it can render the child route's component basically. Read the docs, it's in there.

Comment: Thanks! It seems that I have a lot to rewrite :)

Comment: Finally, I figured out why my code didn't work. As mentioned by @N.K I forgot to include the <Outlet> in my English component.